# 43A shower installed on 40A RCBO

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, uk

I recently had a new consumer unit installed (6mo back). The shower is on a Hager ADA140G breaker, 40A rated.

However,when replacing the pull cord switch for our shower and doing my research, I discovered it was a 10.8kW shower that recommends 45A switches.

Is this a serious issue that needs to be rectified or is it within safe tolerances, given that showers are not left on for hours on end.

p.s. this is the reason for replacing the switch. I'm glad I found the source of the fishy smell.

[image: burnt shower switch]

Comment: You are already burning the switch and wires, maybe from loose connections or too much power needed.  Either replace the shower with a smaller unit or rewire with larger wires to the breaker and upgrade the breaker.  There should also be cheaper ways of heating water than with electricity.

Comment: According to https://www.plumbworld.co.uk/electric-showers-explained-infopage *Showers up to 12.5kw should carry a 10mm cable to units within 35 metres of the fuseboard. Fuses and switches should be rated at 50 amps.* You want a qualfied electrician to do the work, IMHO.

Comment: The replacement switch I have got is 50A Rated. Although I suspect the problem was that the connections were loose. I will get the electrician to return stating that I do not think they did the installation correctly.